# multiple column alignment

Tags: awk, sed, text-formatting

I've my raw data as -

```
   id=ABC name=Banana DB Connection type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_1 ABC.xml
    XYZ_2 ABC.xml
    XYZ_3 ABC.xml
    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    "Fruits/Mango/#Bizzare"
    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"

    id=EFG name=FruitHouse type=jms
    XYZ_4 EFG.xml
    "Fruits/Plum Orange"

    id=JKL name=JMSWriteConnect type=jms
    XYZ_4 JKL.xml
    "Fruits/Plum Orange"

    id=TMZ name=Banana DB Connection type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_5 TMZ.xml
    "Fruits/Mango/Backup/Apple"

    id=LDL name=Banana DB Market-Connect type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_6 LDL.xml
    XYZ_7 LDL.xml
    XYZ_8 LDL.xml
    XYZ_9 LDL.xml
    XYZ_10 LDL.xml
    XYZ_11 LDL.xml
    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    "VEG/Mango/#NOT"
    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    "Fruits/Mango/#NOT"
    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
```

Using shell script (awk, sed, bash) , I want to align as (final output)-

```
   id=ABC name=Banana DB Connection type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_1 ABC.xml "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_2 ABC.xml "Fruits/Mango/#Bizzare"
    XYZ_3 ABC.xml "Fruits/Mango/#Common"

    id=EFG name=FruitHouse type=jms
    XYZ_4 EFG.xml "Fruits/Plum Orange"

    id=JKL name=JMSWriteConnect type=jms
    XYZ_4 JKL.xml "Fruits/Plum Orange"

    id=TMZ name=Banana DB Connection type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_5 TMZ.xml "Fruits/Mango/Backup/Apple"

    id=LDL name=Banana DB Market-Connect type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_6 LDL.xml "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_7 LDL.xml "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_8 LDL.xml "VEG/Mango/#NOT"
    XYZ_9 LDL.xml "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_10 LDL.xml "Fruits/Mango/#NOT"
    XYZ_11 LDL.xml "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
```

Spaces in lines doesn't matter. Any clue would help.

Comment: From raw data point of view: Rows are variable. Actual file is long (scale up-to few thousand rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `paste`, `grep` and `sed`:

```
paste -d ' '\
 <(grep -v '"' file)\
 <(grep -v '\.xml' file | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/id=.*//')
```

The first `grep` gets all lines without double quotes. These are the blank lines, the lines containing the IDs and the XML filenames. The second `grep` gets all lines not containing the XML filenames. Leading space characters/tabs and strings starting with `id=` are removed. Both results are combined with `paste` using a space character as separator.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is always exactly one header line (id/name/type) per record, and provided the record body consists of equal numbers of XYZ_n LDL.xml lines and category (fruits/veg) lines one after another, you could use GNU awk (`gawk`) in paragraph mode, with [Getline/Variable/Coprocess](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fCoprocess.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fCoprocess) to communicate with a `pr` two-column pagination command:

```
  BEGIN {
    RS = ""; FS = "\n"; 
    cmd = "pr -T -s -2"
  }
  {
    print $1; 
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) 
      print $i |& cmd; 
    close(cmd,"to"); 
    while((cmd |& getline line) > 0) 
      print line; 
    close(cmd); 
    print ""
  }
' file
   id=ABC name=Banana DB Connection type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_1 ABC.xml       "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_2 ABC.xml       "Fruits/Mango/#Bizzare"
    XYZ_3 ABC.xml       "Fruits/Mango/#Common"

    id=EFG name=FruitHouse type=jms
    XYZ_4 EFG.xml       "Fruits/Plum Orange"

    id=JKL name=JMSWriteConnect type=jms
    XYZ_4 JKL.xml       "Fruits/Plum Orange"

    id=TMZ name=Banana DB Connection type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_5 TMZ.xml       "Fruits/Mango/Backup/Apple"

    id=LDL name=Banana DB Market-Connect type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_6 LDL.xml       "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_7 LDL.xml       "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_8 LDL.xml       "VEG/Mango/#NOT"
    XYZ_9 LDL.xml       "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_10 LDL.xml      "Fruits/Mango/#NOT"
    XYZ_11 LDL.xml      "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl:

```bsh
perl -00 -F'\n' -anE '
    $n = ($#F + 1)/2;
    say $F[0];
    say $F[$_], $F[$_+$n] for (1..$n);
    say "";
' raw
```

- `-00` splits the file by paragraphs
- `-F'\n'` uses newlines as the field separator
- `-a` "autosplits" the record into fields stored in the @F array
- `-n` loops over the records in the file

```
   id=ABC name=Banana DB Connection type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_1 ABC.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_2 ABC.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#Bizzare"
    XYZ_3 ABC.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"

    id=EFG name=FruitHouse type=jms
    XYZ_4 EFG.xml    "Fruits/Plum Orange"

    id=JKL name=JMSWriteConnect type=jms
    XYZ_4 JKL.xml    "Fruits/Plum Orange"

    id=TMZ name=Banana DB Connection type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_5 TMZ.xml    "Fruits/Mango/Backup/Apple"

    id=LDL name=Banana DB Market-Connect type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_6 LDL.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_7 LDL.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_8 LDL.xml    "VEG/Mango/#NOT"
    XYZ_9 LDL.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_10 LDL.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#NOT"
    XYZ_11 LDL.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
```

Answer (score 0):

With the same caveats as mentioned in the other posts, we can do it by looking for equal sized chunks in a paragraph after printing and removing the first chunk of line from the current paragraph.

The chunks of equal sizes are found by means of regex when the number of newlines match in the two chunks.

```
$ perl -l -00 -ne '
      ($line, $str) = (qr/.*\n/, q/.*\n/);
      s/$/\n/;s/($line)//;printf $1;
       while (
           /^
                ($line)($line*)
                (?{ $n = $2 =~ tr|\n|\n| })
                (??{ $str . ($str x $n)  })
             $ 
           /x
        ) {
          s/($line)((?:$line){$n})($line)/$2/x;
          print "$1\n$3" =~ tr/\n//dr;
        }
        printf "\n";
' file
```

***Results :***

```
   id=ABC name=Banana DB Connection type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_1 ABC.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_2 ABC.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#Bizzare"
    XYZ_3 ABC.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"

    id=EFG name=FruitHouse type=jms
    XYZ_4 EFG.xml    "Fruits/Plum Orange"

    id=JKL name=JMSWriteConnect type=jms
    XYZ_4 JKL.xml    "Fruits/Plum Orange"

    id=TMZ name=Banana DB Connection type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_5 TMZ.xml    "Fruits/Mango/Backup/Apple"

    id=LDL name=Banana DB Market-Connect type=FruitMarket
    XYZ_6 LDL.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_7 LDL.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_8 LDL.xml    "VEG/Mango/#NOT"
    XYZ_9 LDL.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
    XYZ_10 LDL.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#NOT"
    XYZ_11 LDL.xml    "Fruits/Mango/#Common"
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '{print $1; for (i=2; i<=((NF+1)/2); i+=1)
    {print $i, $((NF+1)/2+i-1)}; print "\n"}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Method utilizing pure array manipulations:

```
$ perl -F'\n' -l -00 -nae '
     print $\, shift @F;
     push @A, shift @F while @F > @A;
     print shift @A, $_ for @F;
' file

 -l will make print attach newlines.
 -00 is the paragraph mode
 -n reads file a record at a time.
 -F splits the current record (= paragraph in our case) 
 around newlines and stores them in
  zero indexed array @F.
```